# Are most cross-platform C++ libraries really not cross-platform for game developing?

Tags: unity, c#, c++, cross-platform

Sorry for my poor English.

Some cross-platform C++ libraries are useful for game developing, e.g., Eigen, Skia, OpenCV, Tensor Flow.  I am not sure whether they are really limited to officially stated supported platforms (desktop and mobile only) without supports on game console and web platforms.  Thank you.
 I just want to conform it.  Let me know whether those libraries are indeed very limited in terms of cross-platform portability for game developing.

Comment: Is there a particular task you need to do that you don't find supported out of the box in Unity? If so, asking "How can I achieve Feature X in a cross platform way?" might help focus answers on more constructive solutions that actually move you towards your goal. With your question currently as broad as it is, I think the only answer that covers all the cases you've described is "it depends on the library" — something you probably already know from your research so far. What can we help you solve that will help you move closer to completing your game?

Comment: You seem very focused on C++ libraries. While you can write native C++ plug-ins for Unity, typically C# is what you code/script your game with.

Comment: This still falls under the "what technology to use", as "does library X support feature Y" is used just for that (without mentioning that these are not "time agnostic", and can be answered by yes or no).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know how to properly rephrase my original question.  I try to simplify my question as [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164259/can-i-the-eigen-library-on-any-platforms-supported-by-unity)